# Google Chrome creates history item on redirect?

Tags: forms, google-chrome, browser, redirect

When following a redirect after form submission that goes back to the page you're on, my experience has always been that clicking back on your browser button will take you to the page you were on *before* the page, *before* the form submission.

For example, you enter a site and:

```
1. (click) GET /home
2. (click) GET /user/view
3. (click) POST /user/save_changes
4. (redirect) GET /user/view
```

The behavior in Firefox is that after form submission and redirect (#4), clicking "back" will take you to #1 (GET /home) from #4. But in Chrome, clicking back after the redirect takes you to #2 (GET /user/view).

I don't recall this being the behavior in the past... and it only appears to happen on Chrome. It happens both with `301` and `302` redirects.

Is there a way to avoid this behavior?  I've always done it this way because the behavior has always been acceptable (goes back to #1 upon clicking back after form submission).  I did this to avoid someone ever clicking back and getting the horrible "do you want to resubmit the form" message.

Answer (score -1):

HTML5 provides a cool option to control the browser behavior - HTML5 history API. Guess, instead of depending on the browser to handle on its own, its always better to instruct the browser how to handle it.